# Problem with accents when using ImageMagick or Ghostscript to convert PDF to Image

Tags: 14.04, pdf, convert, imagemagick, ghostscript

I am having a problem when converting PDF to Images using ImageMagick or Ghostscript. All accented characters disappear from the converted image. I found a couple of people having the same problem and apparently updating imagemagick package and ghostcript fixed it, but not for me.

I am using this PDF file on every tests I made: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3gso0sw1e1n8f9r/error-with-accents.pdf?dl=0

I have an Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS server on Azure where I need ImageMagick to work. From the official repositories I have ImageMagick 6.7.7 and Ghostscript 9.10. Later, I tried upgrading them in order to fix my issue and now I have also ImageMagick 6.8.9-10 running on `/opt/imagemagick-6.8` folder and I added Ubuntu's 15.04 repository so I could install Ghostscript 9.15 directly through apt-get. None of these fixed the problem for me.

Here are my latests attempts on the Ubuntu 14.04 server:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

$ /opt/imagemagick-6.8/bin/convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-10 Q16 x86_64 2015-07-30 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC OpenMP
Delegates: jng jpeg png x xml zlib

$ /opt/imagemagick-6.8/bin/convert -list configure |grep DELEGATES
DELEGATES      mpeg jng jpeg png ps x xml zlib

$ /opt/imagemagick-6.8/bin/convert error-with-accents.pdf -verbose -alpha off -resample 150 -density 150 -quality '80' im-test.jpg
   **** Warning: considering '0000000000 XXXXX n' as a free entry.

   **** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
   **** The file was produced by: 
   **** >>>> Mac OS X 10.10.4 Quartz PDFContext <<<<
   **** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
   **** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
   **** specification.

error-with-accents.pdf=>im-test.jpg PDF 595x794=>1240x1654 1240x1654+0+0 16-bit sRGB 172KB 0.440u 0:00.240

$ gs -v
GPL Ghostscript 9.15 (2014-09-22)
Copyright (C) 2014 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.

$ gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile=gs-test.jpg error-with-accents.pdf 
GPL Ghostscript 9.15 (2014-09-22)
Copyright (C) 2014 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
   **** Warning: considering '0000000000 XXXXX n' as a free entry.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1

   **** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
   **** The file was produced by: 
   **** >>>> Mac OS X 10.10.4 Quartz PDFContext <<<<
   **** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
   **** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
   **** specification.

$ convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP    

$ convert -list configure |grep DELEGATES
DELEGATES     bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jpeg jng jp2 lcms2 lqr lzma openexr pango png rsvg tiff x11 xml wmf zlib

$ convert error-with-accents.pdf -verbose -alpha off -resample 150 -density 150 -quality '80' im-test-6.7.7.jpg
   **** Warning: considering '0000000000 XXXXX n' as a free entry.

   **** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
   **** The file was produced by: 
   **** >>>> Mac OS X 10.10.4 Quartz PDFContext <<<<
   **** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
   **** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
   **** specification.

error-with-accents.pdf=>im-test-6.7.7.jpg PDF 595x794=>1240x1654 1240x1654+0+0 16-bit DirectClass 160KB 0.490u 0:00.279
```

All with the same results:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/eob6y234x37s864/gs-test.jpg?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/96z1pkksdn1dpr4/im-test.jpg?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dev0kbza2c8v2gf/im-test-6.7.7.jpg?dl=0

I am able to run Ghostscript and ImageMagick correctly on a Mac OS. And, according to [this post](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=25839&p=124262), the versions I have on Ubuntu should work. So I'm thinking it's something related to FreeType fonts. Which I know nothing on how to fix this. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Kurt Pfeifle on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883953/problems-using-imagemagick-for-converting-pdf-with-accented-characters/31884831#31884831) for the answer.

The problem was the version of Ghostscript installed on the server. Since the latest version for Ghostscript on Ubuntu wily repository is 9.15, I downloaded the official [binary package for linux x64](http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/binaries/ghostscript-9.16-linux-x86_64.tgz) at Ghostscript website.

Then I substituted `/usr/bin/gs` binary with the one inside the package and everything worked correctly. No more problems with accents.

Answer (score 1):

I had to the same kind of problems when trying to print a pdf with accents.
I came to the conclusion that it was a ghostscript problem, since CUPS was using it while rasterising the pdf through `gstoraster` filter.
I also realised that a recent binary of ghostscript in standalone mode was doing a great job.

**BUT** I wouldn't advise to subsitute `/usr/bin/gs` because it could break some dependences (CUPS for example) !

Instead, I suggest you to have a look on the tool `pdfimages` from `poppler-utils`

Comment: the question is all ready solved and there is no need to post an answer. if you have a different problem ask a question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)